# D3js - Adding axes to small multiples chart

Tags: d3.js, charts

I'm trying http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/9490516 with some modifications.

I found this: [D3js - adding yaxis to small multiples chart yields no or overlapped values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19911356/d3js-adding-yaxis-to-small-multiples-chart-yields-no-or-overlapped-values)

But it doesn't really help me.

- What I would like is:
- an x axis at the top of my page
- an x axis at the bottom of the page
- y axis for each chart with different domains

So far, I've been able to add x axis to each individual graph, but that's not what I want.
I'm able to add y axis to individual graphs, but the domain for all are the same.